# Correct way to use multiple coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I just feel like there's a better way to this. I've got a texture that I'm needing to resize, and then compress. Both of these functions need a bit of processing time so I'm needing to put each in a coroutine. The way I've got it is I'm resizing first and then compressing but things seem like they're quickly getting messy. What is the recommended way to structure a number of sequenced coroutines to fire one after the other and pass the processed variable (in this case a Texture2D) from one to the next?

```
[Client]
    public void PrepareServerData(Texture2D texToSend, string typeToSend)
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoGetTexToBytes(texToSend));

        playerObj.texWidth = texToSend.width;
        playerObj.texHeight = texToSend.height;
        playerObj.texFormat = texToSend.format;
        playerObj.tranX = tran.x;
        playerObj.tranY = tran.y;
        playerObj.tranZ = tran.z;
        playerObj.type = typeToSend;
        Player_ID id = GetComponent<Player_ID>();
        playerObj.id = id.MakeUniqueIdentity();
        playerObj.strength = strengthToSend;
        playerObj.hitpoints = hitPointsToSend;

        Network_Serializer serialize = GetComponent<Network_Serializer>();

        // Send Data from Client to Server as many small sequenced packets
        byte[] bytes = serialize.ObjectToByteArray(playerObj);

        StartCoroutine(Network_Transmitter.instance.DoSendBytes(0, bytes));
    }

    IEnumerator DoGetTexToBytes(Texture2D tex)
    {
        DoResizeTex(tex);

        byte[] texBytes = tex.GetRawTextureData();                      // convert texture to raw bytes
        byte[] compressedTexBytes = lzip.compressBuffer(texBytes, 9);   // compress texture byte array
        playerObj.texBytes = compressedTexBytes;                        // set compressed bytes to player object

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        GameObject infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Bytes to send : " + playerObj.texBytes.Length + "\n";
    }

    IEnumerator DoResizeTex(Texture2D tex)
    {
        tex.ResizePro(1280, 1024);
        tex.Apply();

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a callback process to your coroutines.

```
private IEnumerator MyCoroutine(Action callback){
    yield return null;
    if (callback !=null){callback();}
}
```

Usage:

```
void Start(){
    StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(()=>
    { 
        StartCoroutine(OtherCoroutine());
    }
}
```

You can also return values from your coroutine if needed with Action.

```
 private IEnumerator MyCoroutine(Action<Texture2D> callback){
         yield return null; 
         Texture2D tex = GetTexture();
         if (callback !=null){callback(tex);}
  }

 void Start(){
        StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine((texParam)=>
       { 
            StartCoroutine(OtherCoroutine(texParam));
        }
  }

IEnumerator OtherCoroutine(Texture2D texture){
       yield return null;
       texture.DoSomething();
 }
```

EDIT:
Though callback is fine to call a new coroutine, if you had a sequence of coroutines, it could become problematic:

```
void Start(){
    StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(()=>
    { 
        StartCoroutine(OtherCoroutine(()=>{
              StartCoroutine(ThirdCoroutine());
        }));
    }
}
```

In this case, best is to yield each of them. Code also becomes more readable.

```
// Start can return void, IEnumerator or even Task for async
IEnumerator Start(){
    yield StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine();
    yield StartCoroutine(SecondCoroutine());
    yield StartCoroutine(ThirdCoroutine());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need `DoResizeTex` to complete before `DoGetTexToBytes` starts, then you need to call it from inside `DoGetTexToBytes` by using a `yield`:

```
IEnumerator DoGetTexToBytes(Texture2D tex)
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(DoResizeTex(tex));

        // Stuff done by DoGetTexToBytes after DoResizeTex has finished
    }

IEnumerator DoResizeTex(Texture2D tex)
    {
        tex.ResizePro(1280, 1024);
        tex.Apply();

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
```

<s>Edit: it's not clear if the resized texture must be used by `DoGetTexToBytes` , but I guess so. If this is the case, you need to pass the texture by reference, using an array (code above amended to add the reference-passing of the texture). Basically, you're going to use a `Texture2D[]` with just one element, and `texToSend[0]` is your old `texToSend`.</s>

Comment: Thank you for the info but I'm getting an error : Iterators cannot have ref or out parameters at line `IEnumerator DoResizeTex(ref Texture2D tex)`. Any other way to do this?

Comment: That's why I should never answer during the night after a full day of coding, I suggest the wrong solution. :) Indeed you cannot pass parameter to iterators with `ref` or `out`, in order to do so you need to trick it by using an array (which passes by default the reference by value, meaning that any change on an element of the array will be reflected outside the scope of the iterator). I'll amend my answer with the appropriate code.

Comment: But there is only one texture to return. Why the array?

Comment: @Everts For some reason, I thought that `Texture2D` was a `struct` and not a `class`. There's no reason indeed to box the variable since it's already of reference type, my bad. Will correct (again) the code. Just wanted to point out that if the argument was a `struct` like a `Vector3`, then boxing it inside an array is needed in order for the changes to be seen by the caller.